# Power BI new parameters issue

Tags: powerbi

I have set new parameter in power bi

```
Parameter4 = GENERATESERIES(0, 100, 0.01)
```

[image]

but when I input a figure like 60.04 and it will auto changed to 60.01 and so on , may I know how to setup should be ok?

when I change to 100.00 then below info
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvCU8.png)

but when I enter 30.01
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaQYX.png)
after enter the figure will chnage to
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dws2Q.png)
still exists the problem

Comment: It's not clear how this value (e.g. 60.03) ends up on your report page?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enter Parameter4 as a **calculated table** and (sorted decending) you'll get:

[image]

Comment: hi Peter, thanks for your reply , may I know how to set calculated table, when I changed 100 to 100.00 have those unexcepted data,  I have re-edit the question you can see the  second picture

Comment: seems the range problem , if I set Parameter2 = GENERATESERIES(0.00, 10.00, 0.01) ,the problem not occur